Subir una imagen desde flutter + dart y c#
tardes y noches.
Actualmente estoy trabajando en una funcionalidad de subir archivos (Pdf, imágenes) con flutter. He aplicado las recomendaciones de otros programadores en esta plataforma, pero sin resultado. Si alguien me pueda ayudar, dejaré el código que he escrito, de antemano muchas gracias:
Código en backend.

Este es el código en dart y flutter
 Future<ResponseModel> uplodLogo({required File file, required String token
 ,required String path}) async {
 try {
  if (file.path.isEmpty) {
    return ResponseModel(
      code: '0',
      message: 'Debe seleccionar una imagen para subir',
    );
  }

  // * Obtener la extension del archivo.
  final extensionName = file.path.split('.').last;

  // * Obtener nombre del archivo sin la extension.
  final fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

  // * Generar path del api.
  String pathService = '${dotenv.env['URL_PROD']}${dotenv.env['CONFIG']}$path';
  final Uri generateUri = Uri.parse(pathService);
  final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', generateUri);

  // * Agregar el token.
  request.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});

  // * Convertir el archivo a bytes.
  final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

  // * Agregar el archivo.
  request.files.add(
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'file',
      bytes,
      filename: fileName,
      contentType: MediaType('image', extensionName),
    ),
  );

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);

    return ResponseModel(
      code: body['code'],
      message: body['message'],
    );
  } else {
    return ResponseModel(
      code: '0',
      message: response.reasonPhrase,
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
  return ResponseModel(
    code: '0',
    message: 'Error al subir imagen ${e.toString()}',
  );
}

}

Y cual seria el problema?? sin resultado no me dice nada.. no llega el request?? no pasa el archivo?? no llega el archivo??? yo se c# pero nada de dart por ejemplo.. como podria ayudar??? y para los que sean al reves?? esta como confusa tu pregunta.. empeza por alguno de los dos lados para centrar el problema...
